# react font awesome not working correctly in className property

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I have tried below code,

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';

<i className="fa fa-edit" style={{fontSize:28,color:"#FC46AA"}}></i>
```

it shows icon `fa-edit` properly,
[image]
but when i try to use,

```
<i className="far fa-edit" style={{fontSize:28,color:"#FC46AA"}}></i>
```

it doesnt work,
[image]

as per website it is,
[image]

Comment: It maybe a version problem try installing the npm package from https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
<i className={`far fa-edit`} style={{fontSize:28,color:"#FC46AA"}}></i>
```

It is probably due to missing spaces between CSS classes (using string templates)

Comment: i want to use `far fa-edit` or `fas fa-edit` its not working (`fa fa-edit` works donno how?), is it version issue

Comment: Either my answer is the fix to your problem or your css is wrong.